# Is there a way to set a time frame for updating applications?

Tags: applications, updates, system

I would like to know if there's a way to limit when the applications are updated by the system.

For example, I set the system to update applications only between 00:00 and 03:00. If an app has an update available at 15:00, the system won't download and update it, because of the time frame set.

This feature is similar to Microsoft's Windows Update. You can set when the system will look for updates in there.

The problem is that if my device isn't powerful enough, downloading and updating multiple applications at a time will degrade the device's performance significantly, so I would like it to update when I'm not using it.

Comment: Through, Google Play? No.

Comment: System will be able to update apps if only Play Services and Store gets to access the internet. Other than the time period 00:00 to 03:00, keep the Play Services and Store disconnected from the internet. [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall&hl=en) (requires root access) with [tag:automation] can help.

Comment: Are you considering updating apps or updating Google play store ? From your question it is not clear, though I suppose you mean downloaded app updates. Is your device rooted?

Comment: I'm referring to the updates from Google Play. When an update is available, Google Play will download and update the app. I would like this to happen when I'm not using the device, so the performance isn't crippled. I own a Xiaomi Redmi 2. @Firelord thanks for the tip. But I have no interest in rooting my device at the moment. If this is the only way, then I can live without it for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question, it is possible to do.

1. Install [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (not free)
2. Install Tasker plugin [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput&hl=en) (not free)
3. Set auto input to open play store, tap the drawer, tap updates & update all.
4. Note, sometimes for an update a dialogue pops up saying 'this app needs new permissions' you could get autoinput to tap accept or skip a couple of times in case it does pop up.